# Flatten array of objects (key/value pairs)

Tags: javascript

I am having an array of object like the following:

```js
let data = [{
  name: "Product1",
  category: "category 1"
}, {
  name: "Product2",
  category: "category 2"
}, {
  name: "Product3",
  category: "category 3"
}, {
  name: "Product4",
  category: "category 4"
}]

var flattened = [].concat.apply([], data);

console.log(flattened)

// expected output:
// ["Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4"]
```

See above what I tried. However, I would like to have the following expected output: `["Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4"]`

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You do not need to worry about these kind of utilities. You can use either underscore or loadash. For your issue, you can use underscore.js _.pluck method. It is just one line thing. You take any of these library you can use those utilities in entire project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just simple `map`

```js
let data = [{name: "Product1",category: "category 1"}, {name: "Product2",category: "category 2"}, {name: "Product3",category: "category 3"}, {name: "Product4",category: "category 4"}]

var flattened = data.map(({ name }) => name)

console.log(flattened)
```